# Is there a way to get a tailMap or a headMap from an immutable Guava sorted multimap?

Tags: java, guava, treemap, multimap

There are a couple of ways in Guava to create a sorted immutable multiMap. One way is to first create a ListMultiMap with the keys as a tree and then turn it into an immutable multiMap.

Using a ListMultiMap we can have duplicate values for the same key:

```java
ListMultimap<Integer, String> mutableMap = MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();
return ImmutableListMultimap.copyOf(mutableMap);
```

Using a TreeMap we won't have duplicate values for the same key:

```java
TreeMultimap<Integer, String> mutableMap = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural(), Ordering.arbitrary());
return ImmutableListMultimap.copyOf(mutableMap);
```

The problem is that in both cases the immutable interface is generic and doesn't give a way to access the keys in a sorted manner so that we could have e.g. tailMap and headMap which are found in Java's NavigationalMap.

Is there a way to have an immutable sorted multi map in Guava that gives access to tailMap and headMap? Or do I need to just manually build an `ImmutableSortedMap<Integer, ImmutableList<String>>` to get this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You can use your custom `ListMultimap` with [`treeKeys()`](https://guava.dev/releases/31.0.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html#treeKeys()) and cast the resulting map — it's safe as guaranteed by Guava's contract:

> Uses a naturally-ordered `TreeMap` to map keys to value collections.
> The collections returned by `Multimap.keySet()`, `Multimap.keys()`, and `Multimap.asMap()` will iterate through the keys in sorted order.
>
> For all multimaps generated by the resulting builder, the `Multimap.keySet()` can be safely cast to a `SortedSet`, and the **`Multimap.asMap()` can safely be cast to a `SortedMap`**.

Example:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> multimap = MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();
multimap.putAll(ImmutableMultimap.of(1, "one", 1, "uno", 2, "two", 42, "forty-two"));
// {1=[one, uno], 2=[two], 42=[forty-two]}

SortedMap<Integer, List<String>> sortedMap = (SortedMap<Integer, List<String>>) Multimaps.asMap(multimap); // safe, see javadoc
// `.asMap()` directly on `multimap` would give you SortedMap<Integer, Collection<String>>
// SortedMap<Integer, Collection<String>> sortedMap = (SortedMap<Integer, Collection<String>>) multimap.asMap();
SortedMap<Integer, List<String>> tailMap = sortedMap.tailMap(2);
// {2=[two], 42=[forty-two]}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to do it with the `ImmutableListMultimap`? When I call `toMap()` on an `ImmutableListMultimap` it returns a RegularImmutableMap which can't be cast as a `ImmutableSortedMap`.

Comment: Found this similar issue in Guava: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/3775

Comment: Yeah, I think you found the right issue regarding immutable "sorted multimap".